# Связь OneToMany в Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Использую Symfony. Определил вот такую связь

```
//Entity MatchStat
/**     
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MatchPlayers", mappedBy="match")
 */
private $players;
------------------------------------------------------------------
//Entity MatchPlayers
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MatchStat", inversedBy="players")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="match_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $match;
```

Теперь вытягиваю записи таким запросом

```
public function index()
{
    $ms = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MatchStat::class)->findBy(['league_id' => 10869]);               
    return $this->render('app/index.html.twig', [
            'ms' => $ms
        ]);
}
```

И вот в шаблоне твига если я пишу

```
{% for match in ms %}
    <p>{{match.getMatchId}}</p>
    {% for player in match.getPlayers %}
      <div>{{player.persona}}</div>
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

то метод getPlayers() вытягивает записи по одному запросу селектом. Получается, если на странице по 100 записей, то будет 101 селект - первый список матчей, и 100 запросов на получение игроков в каждом матче.

**Вопрос:** насколько это правильно? я помню в CakePHP это выглядело в стиле

`LEFT JOIN MatchPlayers WHERE match_id in (...)`, т.е. нужно было всего два запроса - на главную таблицу и на ассоциацию.

Как это правильно реализовать с помощью доктрины?

Comment: _Как это правильно реализовать с помощью доктрины?_ так, как вы и описали, в репозитории напишите функцию, которая сначала получает все match_id, а потом делаете запрос `WHERE match_id in (...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findBy` поддерживает конструкцию `IN` [Мануал](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

```
$ms = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MatchStat::class)->findBy(['league_id' => 10869]);

// Получаем массив id
$ids = array_map(function($entry) {
    return $entry->getId()
}, $ms);

// Получаем игроков по массиву id (IN)
$players = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository(MatchPlayers::class)->findBy([
    'match' => $ids
]);
```

Но рациональней будет написать функцию в репозитории, которая будет получать нужные сущности по вашему условию

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, уже понял, что доктрина не делает как в других фреймворках hasMany, belongsTo и т.п., через querybuilder как-то правильнее))
сделал в qb `->leftJoin('m.players', 'p')` только не могу понять, каким образом оно формирует для каждой записи массив players, в сыром запросе это же просто повторяющиеся строки

Comment: почему же? В вашем случае MatchStat->getPlayers() выдаст коллекцию всех игроков. Просто вы находите много MatchStat в виде массива и в цикле у каждого элемента получаете много MatchPlayers в виде ArrayCollection. Запрос, сделанный в репозитории может помочь избежать перебора MatchStat, включив его сразу в условия выборки

Comment: _каким образом оно формирует_ вам лучше сделать наоборот. В репозитории matchPlayers сделать `->innerJoin('p.match', 'm')->andWhere('m.league = :league)->setParameter('league', 10869) и вы получите сразу массив игроков